# JavaScript "this" not working for HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to display information in div with `img` element which i'm accessing to database through `php`. I am associating `onmouseover` `event` with each element and passing `this` and some parameters as arguments but as I mouse over on image, div show at top left of browser and does not show beside image.

I have also tried with remove `this` and the result is same old one.

code for image element

```
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

          $firstname = $row['firstname'];

          $lastname = $row['lastname'];

          $image =    $row['image'];

          $phone =    $row['phone'];

          $email =    $row['email'];

     $realtorData = $firstname.'|'.$lastname.'|'.$phone.'|'.$email.'|';
echo "<img src='/../../Realtors/$image'onmouseover='showRealtorInfo(this,\"".$realtorData."\" );' onmouseout='hideRealtorInfo();'>";
```

javaScript code

```
  function showRealtorInfo(element, realtorInfo)
{
    var realtorArray = realtorInfo.split('|');

    var firstname = realtorArray[0];
    var lastname  = realtorArray[1];
    var phone     = realtorArray[2];
    var email     = realtorArray[3];

    var realtorInfoDiv = document.getElementById('realtorinfo');

    var myHTML  = "<p><b>" + firstname + " " + lastname + "</b><br /><br />";
        myHTML += "Phone: " + phone + "<br />";
        myHTML += "Email: " + email + "<br />";

    realtorInfoDiv.innerHTML = myHTML;

    x = element.offsetLeft;
    y = element.offsetTop;

    //alert(x);

    realtorInfoDiv.style.left = y + 100;
    realtorInfoDiv.style.top = x + 550;



    realtorInfoDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';


}
```

css code for div element

```
#realtorinfo{

position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
visibility: hidden;
float: left;

}
```

Comment: This is probably happening because of position: absolute in the css.

Comment: I am not able to see `this` in the question

Comment: i have tried already removing absolute the result does not change.

Comment: this has been passed as an argument to function showRealtorInfo(this,\"".$realtorData."\" );

Comment: Post the actual HTML that the page gets, not the PHP that generates it. One issue at a time please.

Comment: Actually it is PHP that is generating an HTML element. and HTML getting is  <div id='realtorinfo'>
</div>

Comment: So what HTML is it generating for the img that is supposed to be calling the listener?

Comment: this one  "<img src='/../../Realtors/$image' onmouseover='showRealtorInfo(this,\"".$realtorData."\" );' onmouseout='hideRealtorInfo();'>"

Comment: So within the function, does *this* not refer to the img element?

Comment: yeh, if i remove this and coding related to it the div still shows at top left browser showing information.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned "px" in the follow LOC.

```
realtorInfoDiv.style.left = y + 100;
realtorInfoDiv.style.top = x + 550;
```

This should work:

```
realtorInfoDiv.style.left = y + 100 + "px";
realtorInfoDiv.style.top = x + 550 + "px";
```

Comment: awesome it is working but actually its moving in x direction not y direction

Comment: wow thank you it worked i sorted out by rewriting                      
 realtorInfoDiv.style.top = y + 100 + "px";
realtorInfoDiv.style.left = x + 550 + "px";

Comment: please can you tell me why "px" is necessary. i was same code in other code but it was working without "px" but in this code it was not working.

Comment: Style properties use the CSS syntax, so you have to use values like `12px` or `3ch` to make them work. You've probably seen plain numbers in other JavaScript properties such as `scrollHeight` which are not part of the CSS styles and which are implicitly in pixels.